# Скрыть элементы

Tags: javascript

Есть код такого плана, в поле "Тип вмешательства" при выборе ККГ должны открывать доп.поля, при выборе другого значения, скрываться, но что-то никак

```js
 function showDivAttid(){

       if (document.getElementById('first').value == 'kkg') {

            document.getElementById("tr_kkg_date").style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_st").style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_1").style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_2").style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_anti").style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_srok").style.display = 'inline';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_prichina").style.display = 'inline';
        }
        else
        {
             document.getElementById("tr_kkg_date").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_st").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_1").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_2").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_anti").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_srok").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("tr_kkg_prichina").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```html
 <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" class="osc_table_pat">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">Вмешательтва ЧКВ и АКШ</h3>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"></td><td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"></td><tr id="tr_type_gosp" style="display:none;"><td></td><td><input type='hidden' name='type_gosp' id='type_gosp' value='oks'></td></tr><tr id="tr_id_parent" style="display:none;"><td></td><td><input type='hidden' name='id_parent' id='id_parent' value='2'></td></tr><tr id="tr_type_intervention"><td style=" ">Тип Вмешательства</td><td style=" "><select name="type_intervention" id="type_intervention" style="width: 75%;"><option value="chkv" selected>Стентирование КА, ЧКВ</option><option value="akb" >АКШ</option><option value="angiodr" >Ангиография</option><option value="sistromb" >Системный тромболизис</option><option value="seltromb" >Селективный тромболизис</option><option value="stunt" >Стентирование ВСА</option><option value="tromb" >Тромбэкстракция</option></select></td></tr><tr style="" id="tr_date_intervention"><td>Дата вмешательства</td><td><select name="date_intervention[day]" id="date_intervention_day"><option value='0'>День</option><option value='1' >1</option><option value='2' >2</option><option value='3' >3</option><option value='4' >4</option><option value='5' >5</option><option value='6' >6</option><option value='7' >7</option><option value='8' selected>8</option><option value='9' >9</option><option value='10' >10</option><option value='11' >11</option><option value='12' >12</option><option value='13' >13</option><option value='14' >14</option><option value='15' >15</option><option value='16' >16</option><option value='17' >17</option><option value='18' >18</option><option value='19' >19</option><option value='20' >20</option><option value='21' >21</option><option value='22' >22</option><option value='23' >23</option><option value='24' >24</option><option value='25' >25</option><option value='26' >26</option><option value='27' >27</option><option value='28' >28</option><option value='29' >29</option><option value='30' >30</option><option value='31' >31</option></select><select name="date_intervention[month]" id="date_intervention_month"><option value='0'>Месяц</option><option value='1' >01-Январь</option><option value='2' >02-Февраль</option><option value='3' >03-Март</option><option value='4' >04-Апрель</option><option value='5' >05-Май</option><option value='6' >06-Июнь</option><option value='7' selected>07-Июль</option><option value='8' >08-Август</option><option value='9' >09-Сентябрь</option><option value='10' >10-Октябрь</option><option value='11' >11-Ноябрь</option><option value='12' >12-Декабрь</option></select><select name="date_intervention[year]" id="date_intervention_year"><option value='0'>Год</option><option value='1900' >1900</option><option value='1901' >1901</option><option value='1902' >1902</option><option value='1903' >1903</option><option value='1904' >1904</option><option value='1905' >1905</option><option value='1906' >1906</option><option value='1907' >1907</option><option value='1908' selected>1908</option><option value='1909' >1909</option><option value='1910' >1910</option><option value='1911' >1911</option><option value='1912' >1912</option><option value='1913' >1913</option><option value='1914' >1914</option><option value='1915' >1915</option><option value='1916' >1916</option><option value='1917' >1917</option><option value='1918' >1918</option><option value='1919' >1919</option><option value='1920' >1920</option><option value='1921' >1921</option><option value='1922' >1922</option><option value='1923' >1923</option><option value='1924' >1924</option><option value='1925' >1925</option><option value='1926' >1926</option><option value='1927' >1927</option><option value='1928' >1928</option><option value='1929' >1929</option><option value='1930' >1930</option><option value='1931' >1931</option><option value='1932' >1932</option><option value='1933' >1933</option><option value='1934' >1934</option><option value='1935' >1935</option><option value='1936' >1936</option><option value='1937' >1937</option><option value='1938' >1938</option><option value='1939' >1939</option><option value='1940' >1940</option><option value='1941' >1941</option><option value='1942' >1942</option><option value='1943' >1943</option><option value='1944' >1944</option><option value='1945' >1945</option><option value='1946' >1946</option><option value='1947' >1947</option><option value='1948' >1948</option><option value='1949' >1949</option><option value='1950' >1950</option><option value='1951' >1951</option><option value='1952' >1952</option><option value='1953' >1953</option><option value='1954' >1954</option><option value='1955' >1955</option><option value='1956' >1956</option><option value='1957' >1957</option><option value='1958' >1958</option><option value='1959' >1959</option><option value='1960' >1960</option><option value='1961' >1961</option><option value='1962' >1962</option><option value='1963' >1963</option><option value='1964' >1964</option><option value='1965' >1965</option><option value='1966' >1966</option><option value='1967' >1967</option><option value='1968' >1968</option><option value='1969' >1969</option><option value='1970' >1970</option><option value='1971' >1971</option><option value='1972' >1972</option><option value='1973' >1973</option><option value='1974' >1974</option><option value='1975' >1975</option><option value='1976' >1976</option><option value='1977' >1977</option><option value='1978' >1978</option><option value='1979' >1979</option><option value='1980' >1980</option><option value='1981' >1981</option><option value='1982' >1982</option><option value='1983' >1983</option><option value='1984' >1984</option><option value='1985' >1985</option><option value='1986' >1986</option><option value='1987' >1987</option><option value='1988' >1988</option><option value='1989' >1989</option><option value='1990' >1990</option><option value='1991' >1991</option><option value='1992' >1992</option><option value='1993' >1993</option><option value='1994' >1994</option><option value='1995' >1995</option><option value='1996' >1996</option><option value='1997' >1997</option><option value='1998' >1998</option><option value='1999' >1999</option><option value='2000' >2000</option><option value='2001' >2001</option><option value='2002' >2002</option><option value='2003' >2003</option><option value='2004' >2004</option><option value='2005' >2005</option><option value='2006' >2006</option><option value='2007' >2007</option><option value='2008' >2008</option><option value='2009' >2009</option><option value='2010' >2010</option><option value='2011' >2011</option><option value='2012' >2012</option><option value='2013' >2013</option><option value='2014' >2014</option><option value='2015' >2015</option><option value='2016' >2016</option><option value='2017' >2017</option><option value='2018' >2018</option></select></td></tr><tr id="tr_first"><td style=" ">Тип Вмешательства</td><td style=" "><select name="first" id="first" style="width: 75%;"><option value="kkg" selected>Выполнена ККГ</option><option value="aksh" >Выполнена АКШ</option></select></td></tr><tr style="" id="tr_kkg_date"><td>Дата вмешательства ККГ</td><td><select name="kkg_date[day]" id="kkg_date_day"><option value='0'>День</option><option value='1' >1</option><option value='2' >2</option><option value='3' selected>3</option><option value='4' >4</option><option value='5' >5</option><option value='6' >6</option><option value='7' >7</option><option value='8' >8</option><option value='9' >9</option><option value='10' >10</option><option value='11' >11</option><option value='12' >12</option><option value='13' >13</option><option value='14' >14</option><option value='15' >15</option><option value='16' >16</option><option value='17' >17</option><option value='18' >18</option><option value='19' >19</option><option value='20' >20</option><option value='21' >21</option><option value='22' >22</option><option value='23' >23</option><option value='24' >24</option><option value='25' >25</option><option value='26' >26</option><option value='27' >27</option><option value='28' >28</option><option value='29' >29</option><option value='30' >30</option><option value='31' >31</option></select><select name="kkg_date[month]" id="kkg_date_month"><option value='0'>Месяц</option><option value='1' >01-Январь</option><option value='2' selected>02-Февраль</option><option value='3' >03-Март</option><option value='4' >04-Апрель</option><option value='5' >05-Май</option><option value='6' >06-Июнь</option><option value='7' >07-Июль</option><option value='8' >08-Август</option><option value='9' >09-Сентябрь</option><option value='10' >10-Октябрь</option><option value='11' >11-Ноябрь</option><option value='12' >12-Декабрь</option></select><select name="kkg_date[year]" id="kkg_date_year"><option value='0'>Год</option><option value='1900' >1900</option><option value='1901' >1901</option><option value='1902' >1902</option><option value='1903' selected>1903</option><option value='1904' >1904</option><option value='1905' >1905</option><option value='1906' >1906</option><option value='1907' >1907</option><option value='1908' >1908</option><option value='1909' >1909</option><option value='1910' >1910</option><option value='1911' >1911</option><option value='1912' >1912</option><option value='1913' >1913</option><option value='1914' >1914</option><option value='1915' >1915</option><option value='1916' >1916</option><option value='1917' >1917</option><option value='1918' >1918</option><option value='1919' >1919</option><option value='1920' >1920</option><option value='1921' >1921</option><option value='1922' >1922</option><option value='1923' >1923</option><option value='1924' >1924</option><option value='1925' >1925</option><option value='1926' >1926</option><option value='1927' >1927</option><option value='1928' >1928</option><option value='1929' >1929</option><option value='1930' >1930</option><option value='1931' >1931</option><option value='1932' >1932</option><option value='1933' >1933</option><option value='1934' >1934</option><option value='1935' >1935</option><option value='1936' >1936</option><option value='1937' >1937</option><option value='1938' >1938</option><option value='1939' >1939</option><option value='1940' >1940</option><option value='1941' >1941</option><option value='1942' >1942</option><option value='1943' >1943</option><option value='1944' >1944</option><option value='1945' >1945</option><option value='1946' >1946</option><option value='1947' >1947</option><option value='1948' >1948</option><option value='1949' >1949</option><option value='1950' >1950</option><option value='1951' >1951</option><option value='1952' >1952</option><option value='1953' >1953</option><option value='1954' >1954</option><option value='1955' >1955</option><option value='1956' >1956</option><option value='1957' >1957</option><option value='1958' >1958</option><option value='1959' >1959</option><option value='1960' >1960</option><option value='1961' >1961</option><option value='1962' >1962</option><option value='1963' >1963</option><option value='1964' >1964</option><option value='1965' >1965</option><option value='1966' >1966</option><option value='1967' >1967</option><option value='1968' >1968</option><option value='1969' >1969</option><option value='1970' >1970</option><option value='1971' >1971</option><option value='1972' >1972</option><option value='1973' >1973</option><option value='1974' >1974</option><option value='1975' >1975</option><option value='1976' >1976</option><option value='1977' >1977</option><option value='1978' >1978</option><option value='1979' >1979</option><option value='1980' >1980</option><option value='1981' >1981</option><option value='1982' >1982</option><option value='1983' >1983</option><option value='1984' >1984</option><option value='1985' >1985</option><option value='1986' >1986</option><option value='1987' >1987</option><option value='1988' >1988</option><option value='1989' >1989</option><option value='1990' >1990</option><option value='1991' >1991</option><option value='1992' >1992</option><option value='1993' >1993</option><option value='1994' >1994</option><option value='1995' >1995</option><option value='1996' >1996</option><option value='1997' >1997</option><option value='1998' >1998</option><option value='1999' >1999</option><option value='2000' >2000</option><option value='2001' >2001</option><option value='2002' >2002</option><option value='2003' >2003</option><option value='2004' >2004</option><option value='2005' >2005</option><option value='2006' >2006</option><option value='2007' >2007</option><option value='2008' >2008</option><option value='2009' >2009</option><option value='2010' >2010</option><option value='2011' >2011</option><option value='2012' >2012</option><option value='2013' >2013</option><option value='2014' >2014</option><option value='2015' >2015</option><option value='2016' >2016</option><option value='2017' >2017</option><option value='2018' >2018</option></select></td></tr><tr style="" id="tr_aksh_date"><td>Дата вмешательства АКШ</td><td><select name="aksh_date[day]" id="aksh_date_day"><option value='0'>День</option><option value='1' >1</option><option value='2' >2</option><option value='3' >3</option><option value='4' >4</option><option value='5' >5</option><option value='6' selected>6</option><option value='7' >7</option><option value='8' >8</option><option value='9' >9</option><option value='10' >10</option><option value='11' >11</option><option value='12' >12</option><option value='13' >13</option><option value='14' >14</option><option value='15' >15</option><option value='16' >16</option><option value='17' >17</option><option value='18' >18</option><option value='19' >19</option><option value='20' >20</option><option value='21' >21</option><option value='22' >22</option><option value='23' >23</option><option value='24' >24</option><option value='25' >25</option><option value='26' >26</option><option value='27' >27</option><option value='28' >28</option><option value='29' >29</option><option value='30' >30</option><option value='31' >31</option></select><select name="aksh_date[month]" id="aksh_date_month"><option value='0'>Месяц</option><option value='1' >01-Январь</option><option value='2' >02-Февраль</option><option value='3' >03-Март</option><option value='4' >04-Апрель</option><option value='5' >05-Май</option><option value='6' selected>06-Июнь</option><option value='7' >07-Июль</option><option value='8' >08-Август</option><option value='9' >09-Сентябрь</option><option value='10' >10-Октябрь</option><option value='11' >11-Ноябрь</option><option value='12' >12-Декабрь</option></select><select name="aksh_date[year]" id="aksh_date_year"><option value='0'>Год</option><option value='1900' >1900</option><option value='1901' >1901</option><option value='1902' >1902</option><option value='1903' >1903</option><option value='1904' >1904</option><option value='1905' >1905</option><option value='1906' >1906</option><option value='1907' >1907</option><option value='1908' >1908</option><option value='1909' >1909</option><option value='1910' >1910</option><option value='1911' >1911</option><option value='1912' >1912</option><option value='1913' selected>1913</option><option value='1914' >1914</option><option value='1915' >1915</option><option value='1916' >1916</option><option value='1917' >1917</option><option value='1918' >1918</option><option value='1919' >1919</option><option value='1920' >1920</option><option value='1921' >1921</option><option value='1922' >1922</option><option value='1923' >1923</option><option value='1924' >1924</option><option value='1925' >1925</option><option value='1926' >1926</option><option value='1927' >1927</option><option value='1928' >1928</option><option value='1929' >1929</option><option value='1930' >1930</option><option value='1931' >1931</option><option value='1932' >1932</option><option value='1933' >1933</option><option value='1934' >1934</option><option value='1935' >1935</option><option value='1936' >1936</option><option value='1937' >1937</option><option value='1938' >1938</option><option value='1939' >1939</option><option value='1940' >1940</option><option value='1941' >1941</option><option value='1942' >1942</option><option value='1943' >1943</option><option value='1944' >1944</option><option value='1945' >1945</option><option value='1946' >1946</option><option value='1947' >1947</option><option value='1948' >1948</option><option value='1949' >1949</option><option value='1950' >1950</option><option value='1951' >1951</option><option value='1952' >1952</option><option value='1953' >1953</option><option value='1954' >1954</option><option value='1955' >1955</option><option value='1956' >1956</option><option value='1957' >1957</option><option value='1958' >1958</option><option value='1959' >1959</option><option value='1960' >1960</option><option value='1961' >1961</option><option value='1962' >1962</option><option value='1963' >1963</option><option value='1964' >1964</option><option value='1965' >1965</option><option value='1966' >1966</option><option value='1967' >1967</option><option value='1968' >1968</option><option value='1969' >1969</option><option value='1970' >1970</option><option value='1971' >1971</option><option value='1972' >1972</option><option value='1973' >1973</option><option value='1974' >1974</option><option value='1975' >1975</option><option value='1976' >1976</option><option value='1977' >1977</option><option value='1978' >1978</option><option value='1979' >1979</option><option value='1980' >1980</option><option value='1981' >1981</option><option value='1982' >1982</option><option value='1983' >1983</option><option value='1984' >1984</option><option value='1985' >1985</option><option value='1986' >1986</option><option value='1987' >1987</option><option value='1988' >1988</option><option value='1989' >1989</option><option value='1990' >1990</option><option value='1991' >1991</option><option value='1992' >1992</option><option value='1993' >1993</option><option value='1994' >1994</option><option value='1995' >1995</option><option value='1996' >1996</option><option value='1997' >1997</option><option value='1998' >1998</option><option value='1999' >1999</option><option value='2000' >2000</option><option value='2001' >2001</option><option value='2002' >2002</option><option value='2003' >2003</option><option value='2004' >2004</option><option value='2005' >2005</option><option value='2006' >2006</option><option value='2007' >2007</option><option value='2008' >2008</option><option value='2009' >2009</option><option value='2010' >2010</option><option value='2011' >2011</option><option value='2012' >2012</option><option value='2013' >2013</option><option value='2014' >2014</option><option value='2015' >2015</option><option value='2016' >2016</option><option value='2017' >2017</option><option value='2018' >2018</option></select></td></tr><tr id="tr_group_smp" style=""><td style=>Группа СМП</td><td style=><div><input required="required" value="121" maxlength="255" type="text" name="group_smp" id="group_smp" style="width: 75%;"/></div></td></tr><tr id="tr_kkg_st"><td style=" ">Стентирование</td><td style=" "><select name="kkg_st" id="kkg_st" style="width: 75%;"><option value="kkg_st_bp" >без значимых поражений</option><option value="kkg_st_not" >стентирование не выполнено</option><option value="kkg_st_complete" selected>выполнено стентирование</option></select></td></tr>
  <tr id="tr_kkg_art_1" style="">
  <td style="">Какие артерии были стентированы</td>
  <td style="padding: 5px 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[0]" value="1" id="kkg_art_1_0" >левая коронарная артерия <br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[1]" value="2" id="kkg_art_1_1" >ствол<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[2]" value="3" id="kkg_art_1_2" >ПМЖВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[3]" value="4" id="kkg_art_1_3" >ДВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[4]" value="5" id="kkg_art_1_4" >ОВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[5]" value="6" id="kkg_art_1_5" >ВТК<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[6]" value="7" id="kkg_art_1_6" checked>ЗБВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[7]" value="8" id="kkg_art_1_7" >Правая коронарная артерия<br></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="tr_kkg_art_2" style="">
  <td style="">Оставшиеся нестентированными артерии</td>
  <td style="padding: 5px 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[0]" value="1" id="kkg_art_2_0" >левая коронарная артерия <br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[1]" value="2" id="kkg_art_2_1" >ствол<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[2]" value="3" id="kkg_art_2_2" >ПМЖВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[3]" value="4" id="kkg_art_2_3" >ДВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[4]" value="5" id="kkg_art_2_4" >ОВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[5]" value="6" id="kkg_art_2_5" checked>ВТК<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[6]" value="7" id="kkg_art_2_6" >ЗБВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[7]" value="8" id="kkg_art_2_7" >Правая коронарная артерия<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr_kkg_anti"><td style=" ">Антиагреганты</td><td style=" "><select name="kkg_anti" id="kkg_anti" style="width: 75%;"><option value="1" selected>АСК+клопидогрель</option><option value="2" >АСК+тикагрелор</option><option value="3" >АСК+прасугрел</option><option value="4" >тройная терапия (аспирин+клопидогрель+варфарин/дабигатран/ривароксабан)</option><option value="5" >монотерапия АСК</option></select></td></tr><tr id="tr_kkg_srok" style=""><td style=>Срок терапии (мес.)</td><td style=><div><input required="required" value="31" maxlength="255" type="text" name="kkg_srok" id="kkg_srok" style="width: 75%;"/></div></td></tr><tr id="tr_kkg_prichina" style=""><td style=>Причина</td><td style=><div><input required="required" value="232" maxlength="255" type="text" name="kkg_prichina" id="kkg_prichina" style="width: 75%;"/></div></td></tr><tr><td><button type="submit" name="button_action" value="edit"  >Сохранить изменения</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: А что значит "Код не работает"? Как вы это определили? И что за выпадающее меню? Покажите вашу **html** разметку.

Comment: Код HTML добавил. "Не работает" - это в том плане, что элементы не скрываются и не показываются по условию из JS

Comment: Не вижу чтобы в HTML использовалась функция showDivAttid

Comment: прошу прощения, что не указал заранее, данный js подключён к html через  "<script src="... - там прописан этот js скрипт

Comment: На вид код рабочий и должен работать. Попробуйте воспроизвести проблему отдельно, например создав сниппет в вопросе.

Comment: Создал, но почему-то все-равно никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в Ваш `<select name="first" id="first"` добавить обработчик `onchange`, который будет вызывать Ваш код

```
<select name="first" id="first" style="width: 75%;" onchange="showDivAttid()">
```

то все будет работать

Этот же обработчик можно добавить при помощи JS кода

```
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('change', showDivAttid);
```

```js
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('change', showDivAttid);
showDivAttid();  // Устанавливаем видимость по умолчанию

function showDivAttid() {
  if (document.getElementById('first').value == 'kkg') {
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_date").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_st").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_1").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_2").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_anti").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_srok").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_prichina").style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_date").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_st").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_anti").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_srok").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_prichina").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" class="osc_table_pat">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Вмешательтва ЧКВ и АКШ</h3>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"></td>
      <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"></td>
      <tr id="tr_type_gosp" style="display:none;">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='type_gosp' id='type_gosp' value='oks'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_id_parent" style="display:none;">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='id_parent' id='id_parent' value='2'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_type_intervention">
        <td style=" ">Тип Вмешательства</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="type_intervention" id="type_intervention" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="chkv" selected>Стентирование КА, ЧКВ</option>
            <option value="akb">АКШ</option>
            <option value="angiodr">Ангиография</option>
            <option value="sistromb">Системный тромболизис</option>
            <option value="seltromb">Селективный тромболизис</option>
            <option value="stunt">Стентирование ВСА</option>
            <option value="tromb">Тромбэкстракция</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="" id="tr_date_intervention">
        <td>Дата вмешательства</td>
        <td>
          <select name="date_intervention[day]" id="date_intervention_day">
            <option value='0'>День</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8' selected>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
          </select>
          <select name="date_intervention[month]" id="date_intervention_month">
            <option value='0'>Месяц</option>
            <option value='1'>01-Январь</option>
            <option value='2'>02-Февраль</option>
            <option value='3'>03-Март</option>
            <option value='4'>04-Апрель</option>
            <option value='5'>05-Май</option>
            <option value='6'>06-Июнь</option>
            <option value='7' selected>07-Июль</option>
          </select>
          <select name="date_intervention[year]" id="date_intervention_year">
            <option value='0'>Год</option>
            <option value='2016' selected>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'>2017</option>
            <option value='2018'>2018</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_first">
        <td style=" ">Тип Вмешательства</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="first" id="first" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="kkg" selected>Выполнена ККГ</option>
            <option value="aksh">Выполнена АКШ</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="" id="tr_kkg_date">
        <td>Дата вмешательства ККГ</td>
        <td>
          <select name="kkg_date[day]" id="kkg_date_day">
            <option value='0'>День</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3' selected>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
          </select>
          <select name="kkg_date[month]" id="kkg_date_month">
            <option value='0'>Месяц</option>
            <option value='1'>01-Январь</option>
            <option value='2' selected>02-Февраль</option>
            <option value='3'>03-Март</option>
            <option value='4'>04-Апрель</option>
            <option value='5'>05-Май</option>
            <option value='6'>06-Июнь</option>
            <option value='7'>07-Июль</option>
          </select>
          <select name="kkg_date[year]" id="kkg_date_year">
            <option value='0'>Год</option>
            <option value='2014'>2014</option>
            <option value='2015' selected>2015</option>
            <option value='2016'>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'>2017</option>
            <option value='2018'>2018</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="" id="tr_aksh_date">
        <td>Дата вмешательства АКШ</td>
        <td>
          <select name="aksh_date[day]" id="aksh_date_day">
            <option value='0'>День</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6' selected>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
          </select>
          <select name="aksh_date[month]" id="aksh_date_month">
            <option value='0'>Месяц</option>
            <option value='1'>01-Январь</option>
            <option value='2'>02-Февраль</option>
            <option value='3'>03-Март</option>
            <option value='4'>04-Апрель</option>
            <option value='5'>05-Май</option>
            <option value='6' selected>06-Июнь</option>
          </select>
          <select name="aksh_date[year]" id="aksh_date_year">
            <option value='0'>Год</option>
            <option value='2013' selected='selected'>2013</option>
            <option value='2014'>2014</option>
            <option value='2015'>2015</option>
            <option value='2016'>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'>2017</option>
            <option value='2018'>2018</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_group_smp" style="">
        <td style=>Группа СМП</td>
        <td style=>
          <div><input required="required" value="121" maxlength="255" type="text" name="group_smp" id="group_smp" style="width: 75%;" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_st">
        <td style=" ">Стентирование</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="kkg_st" id="kkg_st" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="kkg_st_bp">без значимых поражений</option>
            <option value="kkg_st_not">стентирование не выполнено</option>
            <option value="kkg_st_complete" selected>выполнено стентирование</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_art_1" style="">
        <td style="">Какие артерии были стентированы</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[0]" value="1" id="kkg_art_1_0">левая коронарная артерия <br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[1]" value="2" id="kkg_art_1_1">ствол<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[2]" value="3" id="kkg_art_1_2">ПМЖВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[3]" value="4" id="kkg_art_1_3">ДВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[4]" value="5" id="kkg_art_1_4">ОВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[5]" value="6" id="kkg_art_1_5">ВТК<br><input type="checkbox"
            name="kkg_art_1[6]" value="7" id="kkg_art_1_6" checked>ЗБВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[7]" value="8" id="kkg_art_1_7">Правая коронарная артерия<br></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="tr_kkg_art_2" style="">
        <td style="">Оставшиеся нестентированными артерии</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[0]" value="1" id="kkg_art_2_0">левая коронарная артерия <br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[1]" value="2" id="kkg_art_2_1">ствол<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[2]" value="3" id="kkg_art_2_2">ПМЖВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[3]" value="4" id="kkg_art_2_3">ДВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[4]" value="5" id="kkg_art_2_4">ОВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[5]" value="6" id="kkg_art_2_5" checked>ВТК<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[6]" value="7" id="kkg_art_2_6">ЗБВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[7]" value="8" id="kkg_art_2_7">Правая коронарная артерия<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_anti">
        <td style=" ">Антиагреганты</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="kkg_anti" id="kkg_anti" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="1" selected>АСК+клопидогрель</option>
            <option value="2">АСК+тикагрелор</option>
            <option value="3">АСК+прасугрел</option>
            <option value="4">тройная терапия (аспирин+клопидогрель+варфарин/дабигатран/ривароксабан)</option>
            <option value="5">монотерапия АСК</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_srok" style="">
        <td style=>Срок терапии (мес.)</td>
        <td style=>
          <div><input required="required" value="31" maxlength="255" type="text" name="kkg_srok" id="kkg_srok" style="width: 75%;" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_prichina" style="">
        <td style=>Причина</td>
        <td style=>
          <div><input required="required" value="232" maxlength="255" type="text" name="kkg_prichina" id="kkg_prichina" style="width: 75%;" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" name="button_action" value="edit">Сохранить изменения</button></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

А если в скрываемые строки добавить свой класс, то все можно решить пятью строками на jQuery

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#first').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "kkg")
      $(".kkg").show();
    else
      $(".kkg").hide();
  });
});

function showDivAttid() {
  if (document.getElementById('first').value == 'kkg') {
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_date").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_st").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_1").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_2").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_anti").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_srok").style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_prichina").style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_date").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_st").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_art_2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_anti").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_srok").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("tr_kkg_prichina").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" class="osc_table_pat">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Вмешательтва ЧКВ и АКШ</h3>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"></td>
      <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;"></td>
      <tr id="tr_type_gosp" style="display:none;">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='type_gosp' id='type_gosp' value='oks'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_id_parent" style="display:none;">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='hidden' name='id_parent' id='id_parent' value='2'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_type_intervention">
        <td style=" ">Тип Вмешательства</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="type_intervention" id="type_intervention" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="chkv" selected>Стентирование КА, ЧКВ</option>
            <option value="akb">АКШ</option>
            <option value="angiodr">Ангиография</option>
            <option value="sistromb">Системный тромболизис</option>
            <option value="seltromb">Селективный тромболизис</option>
            <option value="stunt">Стентирование ВСА</option>
            <option value="tromb">Тромбэкстракция</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="" id="tr_date_intervention">
        <td>Дата вмешательства</td>
        <td>
          <select name="date_intervention[day]" id="date_intervention_day">
            <option value='0'>День</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8' selected>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
          </select>
          <select name="date_intervention[month]" id="date_intervention_month">
            <option value='0'>Месяц</option>
            <option value='1'>01-Январь</option>
            <option value='2'>02-Февраль</option>
            <option value='3'>03-Март</option>
            <option value='4'>04-Апрель</option>
            <option value='5'>05-Май</option>
            <option value='6'>06-Июнь</option>
            <option value='7' selected>07-Июль</option>
          </select>
          <select name="date_intervention[year]" id="date_intervention_year">
            <option value='0'>Год</option>
            <option value='2016' selected>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'>2017</option>
            <option value='2018'>2018</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_first">
        <td style=" ">Тип Вмешательства</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="first" id="first" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="kkg" selected>Выполнена ККГ</option>
            <option value="aksh">Выполнена АКШ</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="" id="tr_kkg_date" class="kkg">
        <td>Дата вмешательства ККГ</td>
        <td>
          <select name="kkg_date[day]" id="kkg_date_day">
            <option value='0'>День</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3' selected>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
          </select>
          <select name="kkg_date[month]" id="kkg_date_month">
            <option value='0'>Месяц</option>
            <option value='1'>01-Январь</option>
            <option value='2' selected>02-Февраль</option>
            <option value='3'>03-Март</option>
            <option value='4'>04-Апрель</option>
            <option value='5'>05-Май</option>
            <option value='6'>06-Июнь</option>
            <option value='7'>07-Июль</option>
          </select>
          <select name="kkg_date[year]" id="kkg_date_year">
            <option value='0'>Год</option>
            <option value='2014'>2014</option>
            <option value='2015' selected>2015</option>
            <option value='2016'>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'>2017</option>
            <option value='2018'>2018</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="" id="tr_aksh_date">
        <td>Дата вмешательства АКШ</td>
        <td>
          <select name="aksh_date[day]" id="aksh_date_day">
            <option value='0'>День</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6' selected>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
          </select>
          <select name="aksh_date[month]" id="aksh_date_month">
            <option value='0'>Месяц</option>
            <option value='1'>01-Январь</option>
            <option value='2'>02-Февраль</option>
            <option value='3'>03-Март</option>
            <option value='4'>04-Апрель</option>
            <option value='5'>05-Май</option>
            <option value='6' selected>06-Июнь</option>
          </select>
          <select name="aksh_date[year]" id="aksh_date_year">
            <option value='0'>Год</option>
            <option value='2013' selected='selected'>2013</option>
            <option value='2014'>2014</option>
            <option value='2015'>2015</option>
            <option value='2016'>2016</option>
            <option value='2017'>2017</option>
            <option value='2018'>2018</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_group_smp" style="">
        <td style=>Группа СМП</td>
        <td style=>
          <div><input required="required" value="121" maxlength="255" type="text" name="group_smp" id="group_smp" style="width: 75%;" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_st" class="kkg">
        <td style=" ">Стентирование</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="kkg_st" id="kkg_st" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="kkg_st_bp">без значимых поражений</option>
            <option value="kkg_st_not">стентирование не выполнено</option>
            <option value="kkg_st_complete" selected>выполнено стентирование</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_art_1" style="" class="kkg">
        <td style="">Какие артерии были стентированы</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[0]" value="1" id="kkg_art_1_0">левая коронарная артерия <br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[1]" value="2" id="kkg_art_1_1">ствол<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[2]" value="3" id="kkg_art_1_2">ПМЖВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[3]" value="4" id="kkg_art_1_3">ДВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[4]" value="5" id="kkg_art_1_4">ОВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[5]" value="6" id="kkg_art_1_5">ВТК<br><input type="checkbox"
            name="kkg_art_1[6]" value="7" id="kkg_art_1_6" checked>ЗБВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_1[7]" value="8" id="kkg_art_1_7">Правая коронарная артерия<br></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="tr_kkg_art_2" style="" class="kkg">
        <td style="">Оставшиеся нестентированными артерии</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px 0;"><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[0]" value="1" id="kkg_art_2_0">левая коронарная артерия <br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[1]" value="2" id="kkg_art_2_1">ствол<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[2]" value="3" id="kkg_art_2_2">ПМЖВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[3]" value="4" id="kkg_art_2_3">ДВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[4]" value="5" id="kkg_art_2_4">ОВ<br><input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[5]" value="6" id="kkg_art_2_5" checked>ВТК<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[6]" value="7" id="kkg_art_2_6">ЗБВ<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="kkg_art_2[7]" value="8" id="kkg_art_2_7">Правая коронарная артерия<br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_anti" class="kkg">
        <td style=" ">Антиагреганты</td>
        <td style=" ">
          <select name="kkg_anti" id="kkg_anti" style="width: 75%;">
            <option value="1" selected>АСК+клопидогрель</option>
            <option value="2">АСК+тикагрелор</option>
            <option value="3">АСК+прасугрел</option>
            <option value="4">тройная терапия (аспирин+клопидогрель+варфарин/дабигатран/ривароксабан)</option>
            <option value="5">монотерапия АСК</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_srok" style="" class="kkg">
        <td style=>Срок терапии (мес.)</td>
        <td style=>
          <div><input required="required" value="31" maxlength="255" type="text" name="kkg_srok" id="kkg_srok" style="width: 75%;" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tr_kkg_prichina" style="" class="kkg">
        <td style=>Причина</td>
        <td style=>
          <div><input required="required" value="232" maxlength="255" type="text" name="kkg_prichina" id="kkg_prichina" style="width: 75%;" /></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" name="button_action" value="edit">Сохранить изменения</button></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь, но всё оказалось сложнее чем я думал, код выводится php скриптом типа `array( name=>'first', type =>'select', label=>'Тип Вмешательства', default_array_value=>array('kkg', 'aksh'), default_array_label=>array("Выполнена ККГ","Выполнена АКШ" )),`

Comment: @AlexPilot И что?

Comment: Я не могу понять, куда можно добавить обработчик onchange - логику я понял, и с чистым html понятно, но как это сделать в php строке?

Comment: @AlexPilot обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! заработало! Но вылез кое-какой баг, до выбора типа, по умолчанию открываются все поля формы

Comment: @AlexPilot Ну так вызовите один раз Вашу функцию принудительно. И если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте его как верный

Comment: точно! Спасибо огромное, всё получилось! Галочку поставил!